# Force or otherwise initiate TwoWay TestBox data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I've got a WPF `TextBox` with `TwoWay` binding to a ViewModel property. I also have a `ToolBar` with a `Button`. When the Button is clicked, it executes a `command` on the same `ViewModel` that will do something with the property the `TextBox` is bound to.

Unfortunately it looks like the `Binding` only sends the text back to the binding target when the `TextBox` loses focus. The `Button` on the Toolbar however does not take focus when clicked. The upshot being that when the `Command` executes it does not have the text from the textbox, but rather the last value that was bound.

The Xaml looks like so:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ToolBarTray Background="White" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
            <Button Command="{Binding QueryCommand}">
                <Image Source="images\media_play_green.png" />
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="450" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding Results}" DataContextChanged="DataGrid_DataContextChanged"/>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Sql, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" AutoWordSelection="True" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
</DockPanel>
```

How do I get the `TextBox's` Text binding to update the `ViewModel` when the `ToolBar` `button` is pressed. There is nothing fancy going on in the ViewModel which looks like so:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IMusicDatabase _database;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainViewModel(IMusicDatabase database)
        {
            _database = database;

            QueryCommand = new RelayCommand(Query);
        }

        public RelayCommand QueryCommand { get; private set; }

        private async Task QueryAndSetResults()
        {
            Results = await _database.Query(Sql);
        }

        private void Query()
        {
            QueryAndSetResults();
        }

        private IEnumerable<object> _results;
        public IEnumerable<object> Results
        {
            get
            {
                return _results;
            }
            private set
            {
                Set<IEnumerable<object>>("Results", ref _results, value);
            }
        }

        private string _sql = "SELECT * FROM this WHERE JoinedComposers = 'Traditional'";
        public string Sql
        {
            get { return _sql; }
            set
            {
                Set<string>("Sql", ref _sql, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the binding, setting it to `PropertyChanged` makes the TextBox refresh the binding every time the text changes, not just when losing focus:

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
    Text="{Binding Sql, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    AcceptsReturn="True" 
    AcceptsTab="True" 
    AutoWordSelection="True" 
    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
```

More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Take in mind that if you have a lot of controls on the same screen this will be a performance hit.